# Alignment of tuple of arrays for SIMD load

Tags: c++, simd, memory-alignment

I have a tuple like this

```cpp
tuple<array<float, 4>, array<float, 4>, array<float, 4>>
```

Now I wanna load those arrays into a sse register with

```
_mm_load_ps(get<0>(tuple).data());
_mm_load_ps(get<1>(tuple).data());
_mm_load_ps(get<2>(tuple).data());
```

but the intrinsic requires the memory adress to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary according to https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE&expand=3330

How can I make sure the arrays fullfils that condition or should I use the unaligned load instrinsic

```cpp
_mm_loadu_ps
```

Also can that be generalized to newer simd standards like AVX (by adjusting the size of the array of course)?

Comment: Are you able to pre-allocate more memory, align it with `std::align` and then pass it as `std::span<float, 4>`?

Comment: Hm that might work aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and have something like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t Align>
struct aligned_array
{
    alignas(Align) T data[N];
};
```

and then

```
std::tuple<aligned_array<float, 4, 16>,
           aligned_array<float, 4, 16>,
           aligned_array<float, 4, 16>>;
```

Comment: Can I make aligned_array inherit std::array and put the alignas into the struct definition like `struct alignas(16) aligned_array : public std::array`?

Comment: Not fan of inheritance in that case, but it should work...

Comment: Without inheritance, your version is not at all a drop-in replacement for `std::array`.  No `operator[]` or standard container APIs, and it would be silly to reimplement all of that yourself.  An aligned `std::array` gives @Yamahari what they want, but if you were trying to avoid that it would make more sense to not use a struct / class at all and use a raw `alignas(16) float arr[4]` as your tuple members.